# APA6 style in latex - How can I suppress the title on the abstract page?

Tags: latex, abstract

I am writing my thesis using the apa 6 package in latex. When creating the title page and abstract the thesis title appears on top of the abstract page. Also the abstract is not complete. Notice A is missing when I put ABCD.
Thanks for any suggestions!

I do this:

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    man,
    british
]{apa6}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\vspace*{1in}}{}{}{}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[subsection]{placeins}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
%\captionsetup[table]{skip=1cm}
\restylefloat{figure}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./graphics/} }
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
%\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    backend=biber,
    sortcites=true,
    sorting=nyt,
%    isbn=false,
%    url=false,
%    doi=false,
%    eprint=false,
    hyperref=false,
    backref=false,
%    firstinits=false,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

% maps apacite commands to biblatex commands
\let \citeNP \cite
\let \citeA \textcite
\let \cite \parencite

%%%
% Apa Bib - enable reprint according to apa
%%%

%\input{enable-reprint}

%\bibliography{bibliography}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{Analysis of influencing factors on \linebreak biomechanical parameter of pediatric prosthetic feet}
\shorttitle{biomechanical parameter of pediatric prosthetic feet}
\author{Name}

%\affiliation{Masters Thesis\\}
\affiliation{Technical University Chemnitz\\Institute of Human Movement Science and Health}%{Submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of Master of Science in Human Movement Science}{Leipzig, Germany}
%Prof. Dr. Thomas Milani\\ 
%Franziska Glas (M.Sc.)}

\keywords{pediatric prosthetic feet, design parameters, biomechanical parameters, term working memory, expert domain knowledge}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
ABCD
\end{abstract}
\newpage
\tableofcontents 
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\section{Abbreviations}
%\input{0.Abbreviations}
\newpage

\section{Introduction} \label{chap:intro}
%\input{1.introduction.tex}
\section{Methods}\label{chap:methods}
%\input{2.methods}
\section{Results}\label{chap:results}
%\input{3.Results.tex}
\section{Discussion} \label{chap:discussion}
%\input{4.Discussion.tex}
\section{Conclusion} \label{chap:conclusion}
%\input{5.Conclusion.tex}

\printbibliography

\newpage
\section{Appendix}
\appendix
%\input{appendixfigures}
\newpage
%\input{appendixtables}

\end{document}
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3pKR.png) is what my abstract page looks like. Notice A of ABCD is missing. 
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvmrq.png) is what it should look like.

Comment: Can you please make your code compilable. Remember that we don't have access to your files.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! The title shows up not only above the abstract but also on the table of content page.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of problems:

- `subsection` is not a valid option for the `placeins` package
- the syntax of the abstract is wrong. `apa6` uses `\abstract{...}` instead of an environment and it must be used **before** `\maketitle`
- the documentclass is designed to write articles, thus it seems not very well suited to write a thesis. I suggest to use something like `book` instead.
- to remove the title from the head of the front matter pages, one could temporarily switch to another page style
- to avoid the title from being used as a separate section at the end of the front matter, one can use `\def\def@donotrepeattitle{}`
- `hyperref` should be loaded after the other packages (with only very few exceptions)

---

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    man,
    british
]{apa6}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\vspace*{1in}}{}{}{}
\usepackage{nameref}
%\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
%\usepackage[subsection]{placeins}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
%\captionsetup[table]{skip=1cm}
\restylefloat{figure}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./graphics/} }
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
%\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[
    style=apa,
    backend=biber,
    sortcites=true,
    sorting=nyt,
%    isbn=false,
%    url=false,
%    doi=false,
%    eprint=false,
    hyperref=false,
    backref=false,
%    firstinits=false,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

% maps apacite commands to biblatex commands
\let \citeNP \cite
\let \citeA \textcite
\let \cite \parencite

%%%
% Apa Bib - enable reprint according to apa
%%%

%\input{enable-reprint}

%\bibliography{bibliography}

\makeatletter
\def\def@donotrepeattitle{}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{Analysis of influencing factors on biomechanical parameter of pediatric prosthetic feet}
\shorttitle{biomechanical parameter of pediatric prosthetic feet}
\author{Name}

%\affiliation{Masters Thesis\\}
\affiliation{Technical University Chemnitz\\Institute of Human Movement Science and Health}%{Submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of Master of Science in Human Movement Science}{Leipzig, Germany}
%Prof. Dr. Thomas Milani\\ 
%Franziska Glas (M.Sc.)}

\keywords{pediatric prosthetic feet, design parameters, biomechanical parameters, term working memory, expert domain knowledge}

\abstract{ABCD}

\setlength{\headheight}{27.12pt}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagestyle{plain}

\maketitle


\newpage
\tableofcontents 
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\section{Abbreviations}
%\input{0.Abbreviations}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\newpage

\section{Introduction} \label{chap:intro}
%\input{1.introduction.tex}
\section{Methods}\label{chap:methods}
%\input{2.methods}
\section{Results}\label{chap:results}
%\input{3.Results.tex}
\section{Discussion} \label{chap:discussion}
%\input{4.Discussion.tex}
\section{Conclusion} \label{chap:conclusion}
%\input{5.Conclusion.tex}

\printbibliography

\newpage
\section{Appendix}
\appendix
%\input{appendixfigures}
\newpage
%\input{appendixtables}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful. It works! Thanks a lot for your effort !